# Append new webhook to alertmanager config file using shell

Tags: bash, awk, sed, yaml, prometheus-alertmanager

I am using alertmanager for notification purpose and by default alaertmanager only have one webhook, As per my requirement one more webhook is required.

**Before**

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m

route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: {{ getsdcv "system" "group_wait" "10s"}}
  group_interval: {{ getsdcv "system" "group_interval" "10s"}}
  {{- $repeat_interval := getsdcv "system" "repeat_interval" "" }}
  {{- if not (eq $repeat_interval "") }}
  repeat_interval: {{ $repeat_interval }}
  {{- end }}
  receiver: 'web.hook'
receivers:
- name: 'web.hook'
  webhook_configs:
  - url: 'http://{{ getsdcv "system" "ip" "localhost"}}:{{ getsdcv "system" "port" "8005"}}/'

inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
      severity: 'critical'
    target_match:
      severity: 'warning'
    equal: ['alertname', 'dev', 'instance']
```

**Expected output after adding new Webhook**

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m

route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  group_wait: {{ getsdcv "system" "group_wait" "10s"}}
  group_interval: {{ getsdcv "system" "group_interval" "10s"}}
  {{- $repeat_interval := getsdcv "system" "repeat_interval" "" }}
  {{- if not (eq $repeat_interval "") }}
  repeat_interval: {{ $repeat_interval }}
  {{- end }}
  receiver: 'web.hook'
  routes:
    - receiver: "web.hook"
      continue: true
    - receiver: "web.hook1"
      match:
        alertname: BusinessKpiDown
      continue: true
receivers:
- name: 'web.hook'
  webhook_configs:
  - url: 'http://{{ getsdcv "system" "ip" "localhost"}}:{{ getsdcv "system" "port" "8005"}}/'

- name: 'web.hook1'
  webhook_configs:
  - url: 'http://0.0.0.0:8010/hooks/my-webhook'

inhibit_rules:
  - source_match:
      severity: 'critical'
    target_match:
      severity: 'warning'
    equal: ['alertname', 'dev', 'instance']
```

I tried doing it through shell script but failed

```
awk -v RS='^$' '{$0=gensub(/(receivers:\s+users:)(\s+)/,"\\1\\2- name: 
'web.hook2'\\2",1)}1'
```

I also tried with `sed`:

```
sed -i "/receivers:/a- name: 'webhook1'\n  webhook_configs:\n  - url: 
''" config.yaml
```

I'm not allowed to use `yq` library due to restricted environment.

Comment: Awk typically does not support the Perl regex extension `\s`. Try `[[:space:]]` instead.

Comment: @tripleee awk command used above is not a full proof solution to me, order may change for config file, do we have any other possible way to achieve above requirement.

Comment: Indeed, the proper way to manipulate any structured format is to use a tool which understands that format. For YAML, `yq` is available, with a syntax similar to the popular JSON tool `jq`.

Comment: Thank you, but installing new library is not in priority list to be used. look like proper shell script will be helpful.

Comment: Then (a fixed version of) your Awk script is about as good as it gets.

Comment: yes, can you please help me in that ?? @tripleee

Comment: It's not clear how you hope for it to work. There is no "users:" after "receivers:" anywhere. Did you copy that from an unrelated question with a different YAML structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235299/discussion-between-viney-dhiman-and-tripleee).

Comment: Your edit broke your previously syntactically correct Awk script. The single quotes prevent the variable from being interpolated. You still have not told us where you got that Awk snippet from; it seems to be specifically for GNU Awk.

Comment: I have updated the correct and working Awk script.

Comment: @tripleee I have updated the latest out comes till now what I have done and what was successful, please see if it describes everything well enough

Comment: You still sternly refuse to tell us where you got the Awk snippet from or documenting which Awk version you are using. Please don't ping me any more.